# how can I prove the value of correlation coefficient $r$ ranges between $-1$ and $1$?

Tags: statistics, correlation

What is the proof for the claim that the value of correlation coefficient $r$ ranges between $-1$ and $1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.

$$
\begin{align}
\lvert \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\rvert &= \lvert \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])] \rvert\\
&\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^2]} = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var} X} \sqrt{\operatorname{Var} Y}
\end{align}$$
and reorganizing gives the inequality
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var} X} \sqrt{\operatorname{Var} Y}}\right\rvert &\leq 1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can verify that the finite-mean random variables form a vector space on which covariance is an inner product. The correlation coefficient's range is then equivalent to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for that inner product.